# Parse Query from 2 Collections

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse in an iOS Swift app and am having trouble finding out how to do a query on two collections, i guess similiar to a join.

I have a collection of listings and they contain home information, and a userId.  I have added a key value to the user collection that indicates if the user is on vacation.  The query I am looking to do is to find all the listings where a user is not on vacation.

Here is the parse code used to retrieve the listings, but I have no idea how to add a second condition from the user collection.

```
            let query = PFQuery(className: "Listing")
        query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
        query.whereKey("categoryHome", equalTo: type.rawValue)
        query.limit = limit
        query.skip = skip
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects as? [Listing]
            {
                success(objects)
            }
            else
            {
                let error = error! as NSError
                let errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription)\n(\(error.code))"
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: errorMessage)
            }
        }
```

I was going to do something like this to query the user but I need to add it to the query above.

```
    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery.whereKeyDoesNotExist("onVacation")
```

So, how do I combine those to make one query that looks for all the listings where a user is not on vacation?

If someone could show me a quick snippet, or point me to a sample where a query is performed on two collections that would be great.  I have read the parse doc on relationships, questing, etc. but still cannot understand how to put the two queries above together.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post how you associate Users with Listings, but assuming that a Listing has a pointer to a User, then you could do something like this

```
var userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery!.whereKeyDoesNotExist("onVacation")
var listQuery = PFQuery(className:"Listing")
listQuery.whereKey("categoryHome", equalTo: type.rawValue)
listQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery!)
listQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
   // results will contain lists where the user is not on vacation
   }
}
```

If you'd like to read more about `matchesQuery` then check out the [Parse iOS guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-queries)

Comment: OMG, i think that is what i was looking for. Thank you, i will try it.  And, to answer your wuestion, i have the user id to get from the listing... in hindsight it should be a user pointer. Thanks again, i will try it shortly.

Comment: @LilMoke even in the case where you just use the User id, you could use `matchesKeyInQuery` instead (where userId and objectId are the two keys you're matching). Do be careful with matchesQuery though, because they can be very inefficient if your queries aren't very selective and you have large collections

Comment: Ahhh, good to know. And yes, i got it, i must have missed matchesQuery.  Thanks for the tip.